# Editing iron speed files

Tags: stored-procedures, ironspeed

Can I edit or update the content of a stored procedure in iron speed or not? If I would update it through sql server management studio and i would rebuild my application in iron speed, will my updated stored procedure deleted or not? Please do help me with this. Badly need your ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the stored proc name stays the same it has to work. I've done this before with custom stored procedures where I edit the content of the stored proc in sql server management studio and then resync the database with ISD. Just keep the stored proc name the same.